# How to integrate this product

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I am working on a problem and have gotten to a stage where I need to calculate

$$\int_0^{2^\frac{-2}{3}} \frac{1}{y^3}\cos(\pi y)\, dy.$$

I have tried to integrate by parts (this was a long process) and came up with the following answer

$$\int\frac{1}{y^3}\cos(\pi y)\, dy = -\cos(\pi y)\frac{1}{2y^2} + \frac{\pi}{2y}\sin(\pi y) - \frac{\pi^2}{2}\int\frac{1}{y}\cos(\pi y)\, dy$$

I then considered $\int\frac{1}{y}\cos(\pi y)\, dy$, again integrating by parts, to get

$$\int\frac{1}{y}\cos(\pi y)\, dy = \cos(\pi y)\ln(y) + \pi\int\ln(y)\sin(\pi y)\, dy.$$

I feel as though this process is going to continue indefinitely and am not sure how to progress with this problem.

I would appreciate any help, suggestions or corrections.

Comment: The integral diverges.

Comment: @Dr.MV: so, if the integral diverges, and I want to calculate the value of the integral between some limits, does this imply that the value I want to calculate is equal to $0$?

Comment: No.  The only singularity is at the origin.  So, the definite integral exists provided the origin is not within the integration interval.

Comment: @Dr.MV: hmmm... In my case, the origin is one of the end points of the integration interval.  Is there anything I can do in this case?  Secondly, how do you manage to see that the only singularity is at the origin?

Comment: Yes, in the posted integral, the origin is include and thus the integral diverges - my first comment.  The function $\cos(\pi y)$ is continuous for all $y$ and the function $1/y^3$ is continuous on any closed-interval that does not contain the origin.  There product is continuous, therefore, in any closed interval that excludes the origin.